# Running mmenu with a directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, mmenu

I'm new to angular and tried to create a directive using mmenu, but unfortunately the plugin isn't working.
Any help would be great.

I created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ABMkvE05aP7nVLMlrKAR?p=preview).

Thank you,

```
var App = angular.module('wdapp', []);

App.controller('results', function($scope, $http) {
 $http.get('data.json')
   .then(function(res){
      $scope.bookmarks = res.data;                
    });
});

App.directive("mmenu", function()
    {   
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                $(element).mmenu({
                    offCanvas: false,
                    //counters: true,
                    searchfield: {
                        add: false,
                        //search: false,
                    },
                    header: {
                        add: true,
                        update: true,
                        title: "Navigation"
                    },
                    navbar: {
                        title: ""
                    },

                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `mmenu`, but based on your plunker the most obvious issue is your use of `restrict: 'A'`. This is for **attribute** directives.

You need to update this to `restrict: 'E'` or `restrict: 'EA'` in order to use it as an **element** directive; as you are: `<mmenu></mmenu>`

More info on the `restrict` property: [AngularJS: API: $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-restrict-)